# How to debug with exec in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with the code and I want to run it using `exec(file.read())`. However when I put the breakpoint in that file then it's not reached. How can I run this file and make the breakpoint work?

Comment: Breakpoint in file?

Comment: Yes breakpoint in pyython script

Comment: How would the debugger know what you want? You're just telling the interpreter to execute a string. It doesn't know where the string came from.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the usual way of running Python files, but if you have a `breakpoint()` in the middle of the file, it should work.

I think you actually want to `import` the file or run it directly.

Comment: yes but if I import the file and do the changes inside this file then if I import it again then the changes will not be imported

Comment: That's because you need to reload